# Eigenvalues of complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question regarding eigenvalues of complex matrices. Let's assume that $Z \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with eigenpair $(\lambda_i,\gamma_i)$. We now look at

$B\gamma_i^*=\lambda_i^* \gamma_i^* \tag{1}$

where $(\bullet)^*$ denotes complex conjugate. If $Z$ is diagonalizable, then $Z$ has a unique set of eigenpairs, so in this case we know that $B=Z^*$ (please correct me if I'm wrong). My question is: if $Z$ is defective, can I find a matrix $B = Z$ such (1) is valid? In other words, can I form a defective matrix that shares eigenpair set with its own conjugate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$Z$ has a unique set of eigenpairs"

Comment: Also, why not simply take $B = Z^*$ when $Z$ is defective?

Comment: By unique I, in general, mean that there does not exist a matrix different from $Z$ that has the same eigenvalues and eigenvectors as $Z$.

Maybe I formulated my question poorly (or don't understand your point); my question is if I can form some matrix (with complex values) that has the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues as this matrix' conjugate.

Comment: so a matrix not equal to $Z^*$ that has the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues as $Z^*$?

Comment: Note that for any $A$ and $v$: $(Av)_i = \sum_k A_{i,k}v_k$ so $(Av)^* = A^*v^*$. Therefore you can just take the complex conjugate of the entire eigen equation $Z\gamma_ = \lambda \gamma_i$ to get $B = Z^*$ as @Omnomnomnom suggested.

Comment: Sorry for not stating my question clearly. With respect to your post, tch, my question is; when I have $A^* v^*=\lambda^* v^*$, can A be such that $Av^*=\lambda^* v^*$ also holds (for $A$ having complex values)?